# Postgres JSON Upsert with version conflicts

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to write a rather involved Postgres query and am having some trouble.

I have a table with a single `JSON` column called **data**. In it, there is always a unique `id` field (*string*), as well as a `version` field (*number*). Basically I want to write a query that handles three cases:

([Image of schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56DI1.png))

1. If data `id` doesn't exist yet, then insert the new row
2. If data `id` exists and data `version = oldVersion` then update with the new data.
3. If data `id` exists and data `version != oldVersion` the query should fail with an error.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: I don't want to answer because I don't have a solid grasp of Postgres upserts, but using JSON like this is non-ideal, so have you considered putting these as table columns instead of using JSON?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, with query like this:

`insert into Blocks (id, version, last_version, data) VALUES ('y', 17, 16, '{"id": "y"}'), ('x', 17, 16, '{"id": "x"}')
on conflict (id)
do update set (version, last_version, data) = (case when Blocks.version = excluded.last_version then excluded.version end, excluded.last_version, excluded.data)`

The query fails when the version is different, because that case returns null, and there is a non-null constraint on that column.